# Send a message to a webserver using only the client ephemeral port

Tags: c, windows, port

I'd like to send a message to a server without actually sending any data.
For example, specifying a client [ephemeral port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port) **7273** (is **HI** in ASCII)

[image: hi]

Successively connecting using ports **7279, 8732, 6582, 6932, 8979, 8563** will transmit **HOW ARE YOU?**

The server simply accepts the connection and prints the client port using this C code:

```
// Accept a client socket
struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
socklen_t slen = sizeof(client_addr);
ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &slen);
printf("SECRET: %u\n", ntohs(client_addr.sin_port));
```

**Question:** Is it possible to specify the **Windows** client side ephemeral port?

EDITED: Based upon the comments, I tweaked the suggested linux [client](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/explicitly-assigning-port-number-client-socket/)
to run on Windows and it works now!

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib, Mswsock.lib, and Advapi32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "AdvApi32.lib")

#pragma warning(disable : 4996)


int __cdecl main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
   
    // Initialize Winsock
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

    // Two buffer are for message communication
    char buffer1[256], buffer2[256];
    struct sockaddr_in my_addr, my_addr1;
    int client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (client < 0)
        printf("Error in client creating\n");
    else
        printf("Client Created\n");

    my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    my_addr.sin_port = htons(27015);

    // This ip address will change according to the machine
    my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    // Explicitly assigning port number 7273 by 
    // binding client with that port 
    my_addr1.sin_family = AF_INET;
    my_addr1.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    my_addr1.sin_port = htons(7273);

    // This ip address will change according to the machine
    my_addr1.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    if (bind(client, (struct sockaddr*)&my_addr1, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) == 0)
        printf("Binded Correctly\n");
    else
        printf("Unable to bind\n");

    socklen_t addr_size = sizeof my_addr;
    int con = connect(client, (struct sockaddr*)&my_addr, sizeof my_addr);
    if (con == 0)
        printf("Client Connected\n");
    else
        printf("Error in Connection\n");

    return 0;

}
```

The client/server output is

[image: bind]

Comment: Does this help: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/explicitly-assigning-port-number-client-socket/  It basically says you need to call bind on your client-side socket before connecting to the server

Comment: Call `bind` to pick a particular port. But do note that there is no guarantee that the port will be free at any given time. Some other process may already have that port in use. So the `bind` may fail.

Comment: Are you trying to do some kind of [port knocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_knocking)?

Comment: I'm puzzled about your port numbers, though.  Depending on whether you're thinking big- or little-endianly, I think you mean ports 18511, 22337, 21061, 22863, 21823, or ports 20296, 16727, 17746, 20313, 16213.  (Or perhaps you were using EBCDIC?)

Comment: If you just have all the uppercase letters, you need to bind all the 2 character combinations of 32 65..90, 65..90 32, 65..90 65..90.  That is a lot of ports.  Might be easer if you do one letter at a time with a leading prefix number, say 100 i.e. 10032, 10065..10090.  That would limit the binding to 27 ports.

Comment: That would reduce the number of ports from 676 to 27. Interesting idea! Thanks.